# Writing custom server logs in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I am digging for a way of writing custom server side logs in Postgres. The reason is that pushing these logs to AWS CloudWatch would later allow for automated log processing. So far nothing I have tried worked as expected and constructs like:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION logInfo() RETURNS void AS $$
    BEGIN
       raise notice 'Hello World!';
       raise info 'Hello World!';
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select logInfo();
```

do write logs only on the caller side. Is there a way to have server side custom logs in Postgres? Or is there any other way to push own logs into CloudWatch?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved this one and it is related to log level. Our Postgres instance accepted only WARNings and above so calling `raise notice` has not been logged but `raise warning` has.